# Unsubscribe Ubuntu One Folder doesn't work

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

I have two system and a handful of synced folder (all outside the u1 folder). On one system I took a mistake and enabled the Download-folder for u1 synchronisation. Now at every download a additional upload will start.

I've tried to uncheck the sync checkbox but it doesn't work.
I've tried to unsubscribe via u1sdtool but it doesn't work.

I know it is possible to switch the download folder in my browser. But I would like to have control over my u1-enabled folders....

(I am using Maverick...)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried unsubscribing from the Ubuntu One web interface?

Go to [one.ubuntu.com/files/](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/) and under *My synced folders* there is a list of the folders outside of `~/Ubuntu One` that you have synced. Click on the *More* link next to the folder you want to stop syncing, and then click the *Stop syncing this folder* link.

[image: Unsubscribing to a folder]

Comment: DoR is correct. The best way to stop syncing a folder is via the web UI. We are working on making this work consistently on the desktop right now. Much of this work is focused on the next version of Ubuntu (Natty, 11.04) and will be made available to Ubuntu 10.10 and 10.04 LTS users.