# Sync only selected subfolders to UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've just set up UbuntuOne, and am ready to sync. My Documents folder has the option to sync, but not the individual subfolders. I don't want to sync my entire Documents folder - is there any way to select only specific subfolders to sync?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be an option to do so when you right click on a folder:

[image]

Comment: OK, I just tried that before I posted, and I could swear that the option was greyed out on subfolders of the Documents folder. Just looked again and it's now available. Strange.

Comment: OK, one more question - how do I STOP syncing a folder? I tried to uncheck the Synchronize This Folder checkbox shown in the ribbon at the top of a folder that was previously set to sync, but it greys out and gives me a spinner graphic like it's trying to do something. If I leave the folder and go to a different location, then go back to the folder, the box is checked again.

Comment: @EmmyS See this answer:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/23010/unsubscribe-ubuntu-one-folder-doesnt-work/23073#23073